# Angularjs Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] when migrating to V1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am learning Angular.js and I am not able to figure out whats wrong with this simple code. It seems to look fine but giving me following error.

```
**Error**: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)
```

And before adding `ng-app="app"` (I was just keeping it as `ng-app`) it was giving me following errors. Why is that?

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=Ctrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
    at Sb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:19:510)
    at tb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:20:78)
    at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:75:331)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:57:65
    at s (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:7:408)
    at A (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:56:443)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:299)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
```

```
<!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="app">
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

      </head>
      <body>
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
          <input ng-model="name">
          <h1>{{name}}</h1>
          <h2>{{age}}</h2>
        </div>

         <script>
          var Ctrl = function($scope)
           {
              $scope.age = 24;
           };
          </script>


      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After AngularJS version 1.3 global controller function declaration is disabled

You need to first create an AngularJS module & then attach all the components to that specific module.

**CODE**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.age = 24;
}

angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', Ctrl]);
```

Specifically for your case, there is some issue with AngularJS **`1.3.14`** (downgrade it to **`1.3.13`** works fine). Though I'd prefer you to use <strike>angular 1.2.27</strike> AngularJS 1.6.X, Which is more stable version & latest release of AngularJS.

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2QhTn6sAX2fMyX7rpRRb?p=preview)

**UPDATE:**

You could do your current code to working state by allow global controller declaration inside `angular.config`. But this isn't the correct way to run angular application.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.age = 24;
}

angular.module('app', [])
    .config(['$controllerProvider',
        function ($controllerProvider) {
            $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 7):

I was myself stuck in this issue for sometime. Check for following  in order:-

1. The path to you angular.js script is correct (whether you are calling it in your HTML from a local source or as an external resource).
2. Next, once your angular.js is correct check if your app is initialized or not.

   `var app=angular.module('app',[])`//in your app.js file

   `<body ng-app="app">`//in your html
3. Next register your controller with the app and pass in all necessary injections

   `app.controller('myCtrl',function(){});`
4. Call your javascript file in your html file

   `<script src="app.js"></script>`

Answer (score 6):

You have to define your controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.age = 24;
}]);
```

Comment: are you getting the same error even after adding `ng-app="app"`?

Answer (score 0):

Be Sure that `ng-app="app_name"` define must match to

`var app=angular.module(`**`'app_name'`**`,[])`

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <input ng-model="name">
      <h1>{{name}}</h1>
      <h2>{{age}}</h2>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]); // same to the above define appName
    app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope){
      $scope.age=24; // initialize age by injecting scope
    });
  </script>
</body>
<html>
```

For more details visit [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the version of angularjs in your html file.

> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
> ```

2. Call your javascript file in your HTML file

> ```
> <script src="app.js"></script>
> ```