# A simple AngularJS script is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am following the tutorial : [AngularJS in 60 min](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffastandfluid.com%2Fpublicdownloads%2FAngularJSIn60MinutesIsh_DanWahlin_May2013.pdf&ei=THcJVdKfII2UaqPsgvAM&usg=AFQjCNH4SxCtq4GeuylVMZuithk_eA7Dcg&sig2=USm5jhGbaMzEzptZGs5m_A&bvm=bv.88198703,d.d2s) and I am failed to get working a simple script where the controller is declared on the same page as the view (Indeed it is very basic).
But actually it is not working properly:

So my code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS in 60 minutes</title>
    <script src="./js/angular.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <h3>Instance of model and data binding</h3>
    Name : <input type="text" data-ng-model="city"> {{ city }}

    <h3>Instance of repeat directives</h3>
    <ul>
    <ol data-ng-repeat="person in people | filter:city | orderBy:'city'">{{ person.firstname}} {{ person.name | uppercase}} : {{ person.city}}</ol>
    </ul>
</div>
    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.people = [{firstname:'Valerie', name:'lion', city:'Paris'}, {firstname:'Fred', name:'creche', city:'Marly'}, {firstname:'Laurent', name:'larher', city:'Massy'}];

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

and the result is in the image enclosed.

[image]

Any suggestions is welcome.

Fred

Comment: hello fred if you use angular version greater than 1.2 you  will fail , take  a look at the link it is very beneficial. [https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller]

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727919/angularjs-uncaught-error-injectormodulerr/28728380#28728380

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are using Angular 1.3 or higher. As of 1.3, Angular no longer looks for controllers on `window`. Here is the migration link:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Instead, you should use the `app.controller()` syntax:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('SimpleController',function($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{firstname:'Valerie', name:'lion', city:'Paris'}, {firstname:'Fred', name:'creche', city:'Marly'}, {firstname:'Laurent', name:'larher', city:'Massy'}];
});
```

And change your html:

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: Nah, it happens. Takes far too long to get up the Angular learning curve. FYI, I have a jsfiddle all set up with Angular I use for any of these issues. http://jsfiddle.net/9809ypgx/

Answer (score 2):

In your script you must define angular module and then controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // to do something....
}])
```

and in your HTML:

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
    ....
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.3 you can't define your controller as a global function. You have to register in on a module. For this, you'll have to have a named module (`data-ng-app='app'`). Then, you'll be able to write

```
angular.module('app', []).controller("SimpleController", function($scope) { ...
```