# Angular in intelliJ- issues with the controller

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea

I started to learn angularJs (just in the beginning).
I opened a new project in intelliJ (Static Web).

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Using Angularjs Directive and Data Binding</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="SimpleController">
Name:
<br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
</br>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | order">{{ cust.name}}-{{cust.city}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function SimpleController($scopecust){
        $scopecust.customers= [
            {name:'John Smith', city:'Barca'},{name:'John Snow', city:'winterfull'},{name:'John Do', city:'milan'}
        ];
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason i guess the controller is not bind .. all I see in the web page is Name with input field

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/28728380/2435473

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't `SimpleController`in your Js
At first you need define a module, after that define the controller, like below:

```
var app=angular.module('myModule',[])
app.controller('simpleController',function($scope){
             $scope.customers=  [
              {name:'John Smith', city:'Barca'},  {name:'John Snow',  city:'winterfull'},{name:'John Do', city:'milan'}
             ];
});
```

Now put the name of module in `<html>` like:

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
```

Comment: I did..... in my div. You can define it like this also. Anyway it's not working like you wrote either.

Comment: @SaritRotshild Run it in chrome, press F12, and refresh the page, do you have any error?