# ngTrueValue/ngFalseValue angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am following an angular tutorial and I am introducing myself the ngTrueValue/ngFalseValue angular directives from checkboxes.

When I code like:

```
 <body>     
    <p ng-app="app" >
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.clarooscuro" ng-true-value="claro" ng-false-value="oscuro"/>
            Este campo tiene el value modificado. Ahora vale {{ vm.clarooscuro }}
    </p>        
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Angular says:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp%0AG%2F%3C%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0Ade%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A24%3A186%0Ab%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A23%3A251%0Ade%2F%3C%2F%3C%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A23%3A1%0Ag%2F%3C%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A117%0An%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A331%0Ag%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A488%0Aeb%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A249%0Ayc%2Fc%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463%0Ayc%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274%0AZd%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A83%0A%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A294%3A192%0Ab%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A175%3A62%0AIf%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A365%0AHf%2Fd%40file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fleandro%2FDevelopment%2Fangularjs%2FManualdeAngularJS-Manualcompleto%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A314%0A


...f e?JSON.stringify(e):e;d+=c(e)}return Error(d)}}function za(a){if(null==a||Xa(a...
```

How do I know what Angular want to tell me? Where is written the error message on an angular error message like above?
 The kit of the matter is that the above example does not work
  Regards

Comment: Have u included you javascript which contains angular module in your script?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34864059/2485624

Comment: Don't use the minified version or angular during development. Use the non-minified version, and you'll have much better error messages. But the error here seems to be that you haven't defined any app module, although you're using ng-app="app".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5t5oy8mq/) based on your code.

1. I added the ng-controller directive
2. Directive ng-true-value="'claro'" the inner value should wrap with ''
3. since u are using the minify js of angularjs (src="lib/angular.min.js")
   u can add the ng-strict-di directive it will let you know if there are any
   missing dependency injection annotations.
4. the last thing is the js code

   `angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function() {
       var vm = this;
       vm.clarooscuro = "claro";
   })`

Take a look on the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5t5oy8mq/) I added in order to see the all code.