# AngularJs controller

Tags: angularjs

I've got a employeeController. That employeeController has several functions.

For example:

```
login 
getEmployee
```

This is (for example)my code:

```
   function employeeController()
    {
        var vm = this;
            vm.login = function() {
                //login logic
            }
            vm.getUser = function(id) {
                //receive one user
            }
        vm.getUser();
    }
```

When a employee visits his/her page the employee data must load immediately. But when I login I don't want the `vm.getUser()` method be called. How could I get this right!?

Comment: You are following older way and referring older angular version may be.. refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28728380/2435473) would help you.

Comment: check for the route. If route after login is home, apply this condition when you call

Comment: You are invoking the function `getUser` when controller is called, You can't stop that unless you specify something else

Comment: @PankajParkar, I don't think the question is duplicate __I don't want the vm.getUser() to be called__

Comment: @Satpal OP is not responding to our comments, I'm still feeling that he is following old pattern of registering controller globally.. thanks for heads up though..

Comment: @PankajParker I'm not using the old way.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot put $scope in controller.

```js
function employeeController($scope)
    {
           var vm = this;
            vm.login = function() {
                alert("Test");
            }
            vm.getUser = function(id) {
                //receive one user
            }
        vm.getUser();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="employeeController as ctrl" >
  <input type="button" value="Test" ng-click = "ctrl.login()">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot var vm = this; but that won't solve my question.

Comment: you forgot add $scope to controller

Answer (score -1):

Better Use  call back function to achieve.
**Example**

```
function Ctrl($scope, $http, $q) {

  $http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: url
  }).success(function(data) {

//    do  get user function
      }

    });


}
```