# Angular JS: unable to display value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, ng-app

I am a new learner of Angular JS. Please help me to find reason why [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7yejxcu3/5/)  only display : `{{name}}` instead of showing each values,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Demos</title> 
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="container" data-ng-app="demoApp" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
            <h3>Adding a Simple Controller</h3>
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
        <script  type="text/javascript">
            var samplesModule = angular.module('demoApp', []); 
            samplesModule.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);
            function SimpleController($scope) {
                $scope.names = ['Dave', 'Napur', 'Heedy', 'Shriva'];
            }
        </script> 
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there seems to be no controller or app defined in your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing move `angularjs` cdn file reference before custom `script` to make `angular` object available before using it.

<strike>Thereafter do add `ng-app="samples"` on `html` element & `ng-controller="SimpleController"` on `body` tag will solve your issue.</strike>
(Removed above line as OP modified his code after I answered).

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Comment: oh ! thanks , My mistake in my original code was `First thing move angularjs cdn file reference before custom script to make angular object available before using it.`

Comment: @Ashu you also need to add `ng-app` & `ng-controller` directive to make it working as I suggested in answer..did you looked at plunkr?

Comment: Can you please update this New Similar fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/7yejxcu3/9/   ,this is not working, plz tell me reason too

Comment: Sure I'll look at it once I will have access to machine.. But ideally you could open new question, as you have already got answer for this question..

Comment: Basically you are following older way of defining controller, do refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28728380/2435473) would solve your issue

Comment: thanks it worked. I didn't ask new question because I feel it will scam this website by asking similar kind of multiple question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare the controller and so for the app.
Edit as following : `<div class="container" data-ng-controller="SimpleController"` and `<body data-ng-app="samples">`

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `ng-app` and `ng-controller` to your View.

```
   <body > 
        <div ng-app="samples" class="container"  ng-controller="SimpleController">
            <h3>Looping with the ng-repeat Directive</h3>
            <h4>Data to loop through is initialized using ng-init</h4>
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </body>
```

Here is the working [`app`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/7yejxcu3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the order in your file, no other operations necessary. See below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Demos</title> 
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body> 
    <script  type="text/javascript">
      var samplesModule = angular.module('demoApp', []); 
      samplesModule.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);
      function SimpleController($scope) {
        $scope.names = ['Dave', 'Napur', 'Heedy', 'Shriva'];
      }
    </script> 
    <div class="container" data-ng-app="demoApp" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
      <h3>Adding a Simple Controller</h3>
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```