# Simple example AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An example of displaying data with AngularJS when a button is pushed is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
function Display($scope){
    $scope.show_date = function(){
        $scope.show=new Date();
    }       
}   
 </script>
</head>
<body  ng-controller="Display">
<button ng-click="show_date()">Show date!</button>
<div ng-message="required"> {{show}} </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where I was wrong in this code?

Comment: Your declaration of the controller is using an outdated syntax

Comment: what is the problem in reading documentation and seeing the basic?

Comment: You could refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28728380/2435473), you are just following old way of doing it like @tymeJV said

Comment: also provide the errors when posting code that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular version above 1.3, Basically from there on  global controller function declaration is not supoorted

Change your controller as below,

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", [])
 myApp.controller("Display", function ($scope) 
 {
    $scope.show_date = function(){
    $scope.show=new Date();
  }     
 );
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oAeARYHFkfDuHrRPTez7?p=preview)

Comment: Basically 1.3+ remove global declaration of controller, checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28728380/2435473)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

You just need to define an instance of your app module:

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

And then you need to register your controller will this app module:

```
.controller('DisplayCtrl', DisplayCtrl);
```

Click on `Run code snippet` to see your code working.

```js
function DisplayCtrl($scope){
    $scope.show_date = function(){
        $scope.show=new Date();
    }       
}   

angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('DisplayCtrl', DisplayCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DisplayCtrl">
  <button ng-click="show_date()">Show date!</button>
  <div ng-message="required"> {{show}} </div>
</div>
```