# Angular js binding expression does not show value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The index.html page looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"/>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.14/angular.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
<div>
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
<div>
    {{person.firstName}}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The script.js file looks like this:

```
var MainController = function($scope) {
var person = {
    firstName : "Nagendra"
};
$scope.person = person;
$scope.message = "Hello Angular!";
};
```

But when I boot up the application my page shows :

```
{{message}}

{{person.firstName}}
```

and not the values that it should. Am I missing something here? I am using spring boot.
I have debugged the chrome and have seen the js file loading properly, it even hits the debugger point in the js file,hence the file loading is not the problem i suppose.

> UPDATE- THIS WORKED

```
var MainController = function($scope) {
var person = {
    firstName: "Nagendra"
};
$scope.person = person;
$scope.message = "Hello Angular!";
};


angular.module('mainApp', [])
.controller('MainController', MainController);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.14/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
<div>
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
<div>
    {{person.firstName}}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since angular 1.3+ [**global function declaration of controller haven't been supported**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28728380/2435473). So you have first create an angular module and then bind all of its angular component to it.

Also move `/js/script.js` right after `angular.js` reference with closing `</script>` tag.

**Code**

```
angular.module('mainApp', [])
.controller('MainController', MainController)
function MainController($scope) {
    var person = {
        firstName: "Nagendra"
    };
    $scope.person = person;
    $scope.message = "Hello Angular!";
};
```

Then do add `mainApp` module inside `ng-app` directive like `ng-app="mainApp"` on html tag.

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wBaSFoeTmnjfJFPcRKBm?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I changed my angular server to. `<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0rc1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular.js"></script>` and it worked.

Comment: That's what I said in my answer, that doesn't mean you should downgrade your application to make it work.. upgrade it to latest 1.5.8 and just enjoy the coolest angular..

Comment: its saying module mail app is not available when i see in the console.

Comment: Ok, so script file for angular needed to be moved up, but still I am not able to see the value.

Comment: @Nagendra555 you should move `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"/>` right after angular js

Comment: @Nagendra555 check updated answer, it has the same thing what you had in question, all things are corrected in plunk version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the module and the controller,

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
  {{message}} {{person.firstName}}
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('DemoApp', ['angular.filter'])
app.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
var person = {
    firstName : "Nagendra"
};
$scope.person = person;
$scope.message = "Hello Angular!";

});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/UkenlTZNJT77oFuDzF6i?p=preview)**

Comment: Just saw, why did you add angular.filter.

Comment: @Nagendra555 that is not needed