# My function is not accessing the controller.js

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-controller

my controller.js file

```
function ServicesCtrl($scope) {
    console.log("Hello From ServicesCtrl");
    $scope.message = "Hello";       
}
```

index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>The MEAN Stack</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="features/services/controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="ServicesCtrl">
        <h1>Service Client Maker</h1>
        {{message}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it is not displaying my message. controller.js file is not accessable

Comment: You have to create an angular module first and add controller to that module, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28728380/2435473) would help you..

Comment: You should look at the first two getting started pages on the angularjs official page.

Answer (score 1):

Its clear that you are trying to define a controller like a simple js function.
But, It works in a different way. 

You have to initialize an angular app within an java-script variable like this,

```js
var app=angular.module("MyApp");
```

and handle that entire angular application, through that js variable "app".

I strongly recommend you to completely go through below tutorials.. Then, Start creating the App..

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_mvc_architecture.htm
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp

Comment: tysm sir! it worked!!

Comment: @AbdulHannan You're Welcome.. Confirm it as the answer for your question, by marking tick icon at left side of my answer (below voting icons).. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your angular application and its modules.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('serviceController', function() {
    $scope.message = "Nice, I now know how to create an angular app";
})
```

And you will now be able to access it on your page:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">...
    <div ng-controller="serviceController">...
        {{message}}
```

This should help you since you're getting started with angular.

Comment: **still not working** bro :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here this example
define your controller name (controller.js)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ServicesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello";
});
```

define your app name (index.html)

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="ServicesCtrl">
        <h1>Service Client Maker</h1>
        {{message}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: not working .. :/