# Ruby on Rails script not being loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, ajax, asset-pipeline

In my ruby on rails application, I'm generating a view via an ajax call.

I'm using following piece of code.

```
$("#a_div_id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'index')%>");
```

And the view I'm trying to render is _index.html.erb:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>

<script>

    alert('first');

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

        alert('second');

        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    });

    alert('third');

</script>
```

When I render the view, I'm getting only first and third messages. However, when I add this piece of code into dashboard.html.erb rather than rendering it via the ajax code, it perfectly works.

In the first case, I'm getting the following error.

```
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274)
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:38
    at n (angular.min.js:7)
    at g (angular.min.js:37)
    at eb (angular.min.js:41)
    at c (angular.min.js:19)
    at yc (angular.min.js:20)
    at Zd (angular.min.js:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:294)
    at fire (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:3233)
```

I'm be at my wits' end, I couln't decide what I'm missing,

Any suggestions,

Thanks.
​

Answer (score 0):

Can you try without `escape_javascript`.
Also put a `debugger` like this, this will put a break point when chrome executes the js.

```
debugger;
$("#a_div_id").html("<%= render 'index' %>");
```

That would help you see what exactly jquery is trying to add as HTML.

If this doesn't work,

Probably you should take the js in `script` tag and put it in some method and call that method after you have added index to dom.

```
$("#a_div_id").html("<%= render 'index' %>");
myMethodToRenderAngular();
```

Comment: I've tries omitting escape_javascript it didn't work. I've also tried loading angularJS after rendering index, it didn't work as well.

Comment: Do you see errors in browser console? put debugger above `$scope.firstName = "John";` and then run one step at a time

Comment: Yeap. Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4458
    at n (angular.js:340)
    at g (angular.js:4419)
    at eb (angular.js:4344)
    at c (angular.js:1676)
    at yc (angular.js:1697)
    at Zd (angular.js:1591)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:29013)
    at fire (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:3233)

Comment: hard to make sense of error in comment. can you update you question with error details

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727919/angularjs-uncaught-error-injectormodulerr

Comment: To me it looks like angular issue than rails